# MVC4 : Using default internet application template to create own login portal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-4

Yesterday I tried to create own Login portal using MVC4's empty template. Added a database, user details gets saved there and he can login(nothing fancy). But I now want to use default internet application(could use lots of authorization techniques from there). First I just wanted to add a database and send the registration details to the database I just added but then I don't know how to send it to the new database. Right now it has default connection(don't know to which database it connects, at least not the one I added).

I tried to look around in google and youtube where I could get some tutorial to add a database to default internet application and then send data to it but i get loads of things which doesn't really match what I'm looking for. Anyone knows about any article or videos that can help me get started?

To start I added a Sqlservercompact 4.0 with name AdminPortal and added a Table called Users
Then I added certain fields like FirstName, LastName, Id(Primary Key, Identity = True, Identity seed and increment = 1), UserName and Password. These are the exact fields that I have in register model.
I then installed EntityFrameWork.sqlservercompact using nuget for data binding.
Then I changed the usercontext class as follows

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
    {
        public UsersContext()
            : base("AdminPortal")
        {
        } 

        public DbSet<RegisterModel> Users { get; set; }
    }
```

and web.config's connectionstring as follows

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AdminPortal" connectionString="Data Source=c:\users\biplov\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\AdminPortal\AdminPortal\App_Data\AdminPortal.sdf" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

but this doesn't work, I get error on

```
LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
```

of the `Initializesimplemembershipattribute` class.

Can you please refer me some tutorials or explain what needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

This error usually seen because of wrong Connection String. The problem is from your connection str in web.config. Your constr should be like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AdminPortal" connectionString="Data source= your_dbInstance_name; AttachDbFileName=c:\users\biplov\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\AdminPortal\AdminPortal\App_Data\AdminPortal.sdf;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

hope to be useful

Comment: So in my case connection string is `Users` right? I'm guessing from this line `public DbSet<RegisterModel> Users { get; set; }`

Comment: No! Users is a collection. Your constr is AdminPortal. in this error, you don't have any work with `Users`. Just change your constr.